# How to optimally add a new column with a default in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have 10M rows in a production table and want to minimize locking. My initial plan was to migrate in batches of 10k, but my primary column is an alphanumeric UUID and I don't have a monotonically increasing integer value in any other columns.

For those who have dealt with this problem, what is the best strategy for performing this one-time migration?

I know that initial column creation as NULLABLE is cheap and preferred, which is my initial approach. I was thinking about using a mix of queries with `OFFSET`, but see that can be costly as the offset increases.

I'm not needing to do this solely in SQL, but open to writing an external program to handle the batching.

#### Pseudocode

```
start = 0
chunk = 10_000

for start < 8_000_000; start += chunk:
    // perform update on 10k batch
```

Basic idea above, but most likely over simplifying.

Comment: From docs [Alter Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html): *When a column is added with ADD COLUMN and a non-volatile DEFAULT is specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for the column for all existing rows. If no DEFAULT is specified, NULL is used. In neither case is a rewrite of the table required.*.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver to clarify, I'm interested in applying a default to backfill all null values.

Comment: That is different from this `..new column with a default in Postgres?`. **Add to your question an example query showing  what you want to do.**

Comment: Could you not use [gen_random_uuid ()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) for the backfill along with `unique` on the colum?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on the exact batch size, here are two ideas:

1. if you want to use the `uuid` to partition the table into batches, you could use the first byte. You'd have to convert the `uuid` to a `bytea` first:

   ```
   WHERE substr(('\x' || translate(uuidcol::text, '-', ''))::bytea, 1, 1) = '\x01'::bytea
   ```
2. use the table block number, which is the first part of the physical address:

   ```
   WHERE ctid >= '(0,1)' AND ctid < '(1000,1)'
   ```

The second solution is appealing froma performance point of view, but `ctid` changes whenever a row is updated, so your updates should recognize and skip rows that were already updated.

Comment: Interesting idea. To make sure I'm following, what would the upperbound be on batch size for an approach like this, if there is one?

Comment: For the first part, the upper bound is clear (`FF`). For the second, calculate `pg_relation_size` and divide it by 8K to get the number of blocks.